# How can I disable select2 jQuery plugin on tablets?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, detection, tablet

I am using the [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) jQuery plugin to enhance `<select>` elements in our project. However, on mobile devices (smartphones, tablets), Select2 actually degrades the experience. The native select elements are better, in my opinion.

We're already doing smartphone detection with regexps from http://detectmobilebrowser.com/, but these don't match tablets (and we would like to keep smartphone and tablet detection separate). Is there any reference for tablet regexps like detectmobilebrowswer.com, or another way of detecting tablets?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

function checkSize(){
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)").matches) {
    $("select").select2();
  } else {
    $("select").select2("destroy");
  }
}
```

Comment: A tablet doesn't become another type of device if you resize the window?

Comment: Above solution only works on basis of screen resolution, there is no device detection. Generally assumed bigger than 1024px will be desktop experience.

Answer (score -3):

You can research yourself what the User agents of tables are.

If you know the User agents of the tables you could include the appropriate Javascript files accordingly via PHP or whatever.

[Follow this link to find tablet user agents](http://tinyurl.com/cuj8fag)

Comment: I don't consider "Let me google that for you" a useful answer.